# Jquery Autocomplete not loading

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

Jquery Autocomplete not working i dont know why same code working on my other form but not working in this form...
please help i dont know why its not routing on action

```html
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Lot_no, new { @class = "text-field validate[required]"})
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Lot_ID)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        

        $("#Lot_no").autocomplete({

            source: function (request, response) {
                alert('ss')
                var LotList = new Array();
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,                    
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetAutoFillData", "StoreParts")',
                    data: { "LotNumber": request.term },
                          success: function (data) {
                 
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
      LotList[i] = {label: data[i].Lot_no, Id: data[i].Lot_ID, Cost: data[i].TotalCost_AED };
                            }


                            if (data.length > 0) {

                              response(LotList);

                            }
                            else {
                                response([{ label: 'No results found.', Id: -1 }]);
                            }
                        
                    }

                    }

                });

            },
          
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
  public JsonResult GetAutoFillData(string LotNumber)
        {


            List<ScrapSaleModel> result = new List<ScrapSaleModel>();

            Cls_ScrapSale ObjAutoFill = new Cls_ScrapSale();


            DataTable dt = ObjAutoFill.getLOTNumberAuto(1, LotNumber);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                {
                    result.Add(new ScrapSaleModel { Lot_ID = Convert.ToInt32(item["Lot_ID"]), Lot_no = item["Lot_Number"].ToString(), TotalCost_AED = Convert.ToDecimal(item["COST"]) });

                }

            }


            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Files are included perfectly
Please help me out

Comment: is your action called?

Comment: no thats the problem action not calling

Comment: have you seen console on firebug, if any error coming

Comment: i have seen no errors showing...its blank

Comment: do you see alert('ss')??

Answer (score 0):

Either decorate your `ActionMethod` - `GetAutoFillData` with `[HttpPost]` attribute at top  as below:

```
[HttpPost] //Put this
public JsonResult GetAutoFillData(string LotNumber)
{
      //Remaining Code   
}
```

or remove `type:'POST'` from `ajax` and keep `type:'GET'` as below:

```
$.ajax({
        async: false,                    
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        //Other Codes
});
```